# Length of a circular permutation cycle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, chaos-theory, permutation-cycles

**Question.** Consider a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \,$  which collects the elements by columns and arranges them on rows.

After how many consecutive transformations do you obtain the initial matrix?

**Example.** For a $3\times 2$ matrix, we have
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
1  & 4  \\ 
2  & 5\\ 
3 & 6 
\end{pmatrix} \overset{T}{\rightarrow}
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 2  \\ 
3  & 4\\ 
5 & 6 
\end{pmatrix} \overset{T}{\rightarrow}
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 3  \\ 
5  & 2\\ 
4 & 6 
\end{pmatrix} \overset{T}{\rightarrow}
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 5  \\ 
4  & 3\\ 
2 & 6 
\end{pmatrix} \overset{T}{\rightarrow}
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 4  \\ 
2  & 5\\ 
3 & 6 
\end{pmatrix} \,\,. $$

Therefore the cycle length is $N(3,2)=4\,.$

**Ideas and more questions.**
The transformation $T$ can be described more rigorously using the vec operator as
$$ T(A_{m \times n }) =   \left( \text{vec}^{-1}_{n,m} ( \text{vec}_{m,n} (A) )  \right)^\mathsf{T} $$
where $^\mathsf{T}$ denotes the transpose, $vec_{m,n}$ the vectorization of a $m \times n$ matrix and $\text{vec}^{-1}_{m,n}$ the inverse of the vec operator such that
$$ \text{vec}^{-1}_{m,n} ( \text{vec}_{m,n} (X) ) = X \quad \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \,,$$
$$ \text{vec}_{m,n} ( \text{vec}^{-1}_{m,n} (x) ) = x \quad \in \mathbb{R}^{mn\times 1} \,.$$

How can $N$ be found from
$$ \underbrace{T(\ldots(T}_{N\text{ times}}(A))) = A  \,\,?$$
Is there any fixed-point theorem that could be used?

Note that for a square matrix $A$ our transformation $T$ simplifies to the regular matrix transpose. That is, the cycle length $N(m,n) = 2$ for $m=n$. Another observation is that the cycle length is symmetrical w.r.t. the number of rows and columns, i.e. $N(m,n) = N(n,m)$.

By tracking the position of an element in a $m \times n $ matrix, one can obtain the map that gives the  next position as following
\begin{align}
T_k & =  m(y_k - 1) + x_k \\
 x_{k+1} & = \text{ceil}\left(\frac{T_k}{n} \right) \\ 
 y_{k+1} & = T_k - n(x_{k+1} - 1) \,,\\
\end{align}
where $x_{k+1}$ and $y_{k+1}$ specify on which row and column the element currently at $x_k$ and $y_k$ will be after the next transformation. Is there any way to calculate analytically the period of this map? Is this related to [Arnold's Cat Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map)?

Lastly, let me show you two plots of the orbit length vs. the number of rows and columns. The first one is on a linear scale, while the second one on a log scale. Only the upper triangular was plotted due to symmetry. How do these layers occur?

[image: Cycle length vs. number of rows and columns]
[image: Cycle length vs. number of rows and columns on a log scale]

This question was born from a card trick I was playing with a couple of years ago. Any suggestions on how to study this problem are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried separating out the results according to whether n,m share a common factor? I reckon that it is worth investigating cases with n,m coprime first, and only then seeing what happens when they have a non-trivial gcd.

Comment: Your intuition is right. It has to do with the idea of primitive root modulo n. I got a lead in the literature about card shuffling. For example, if n=2 my transformation is the inverse of the popular faro card shuffle. I'll be back once I find a satisfactory answer.